# Using a pretrained model in Node-Red for deployment\production stage

Tags: node.js, tensorflow, node-red

I've designed a machine learning model to classify events based on some sensors data in [colab](https://colab.research.google.com/notebooks/intro.ipynb). The saved model is saved as `classifier.h5`. So I want to use this hierarchical data format 5 file in Node-Red to simulate the deployment\production stage of Machine learning. As per information available [here](https://flows.nodered.org/node/node-red-contrib-tensorflow), I've installed `node-red-contrib-tensorflow` in my palette (Node-Red). I want to feed the data from sensor nodes in Node-Red to the pre-trained model classifying the events. Can I use the `.h5` file format directly or do I need to convert it to something else? Is there any other way than using `node-red-contrib-tensorflow`? How can I use `node-red-contrib-tensorflow` in my situation?

Thank you.

Comment: Have you asked the author of `node-red-contrib-tensorflow`?

Comment: @hardillb I hope somebody who has implemented it would help with some insight on it.

Comment: Raising an issue against the node to ask the author is going to get you a definitive answer a lot quicker than asking here.